# How to iterate over all keys of a json with nested dictionaries and lists?

Tags: python, json, recursion, python-2.x

I need to modify the following json file, test.json:

```
{
  "install": {
    "site": {
      "acls": {
        "dns": {
          "authorized_ports": ["53:tcp", "53:udp"]
        }
      },
      "network": {
        "clusters": {
          "__ip_range_1__": {
            "dhcpstart": "__ip__",
            "dhcpend": "__ip__",
            "adminip": "__ip__"
          },
          "__ip_range_2__": {
            "dhcpstart": "__ip__",
            "dhcpend": "__ip__",
            "adminip": "__ip__"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The above is abbreviated, there are many more entries in the original file.  I have several of these files per site and thus `__ip_range_x__` is different in each file and so is every IP.  I need to add entries to each `__ip_range_x__` element.  The new entry is a dictionary of dictionaries (`interface_config` below) stored in mod.json:

```
{
  "path": "{install}{site}{network}{clusters}{*}",
  "install" :  {
    "site": {
      "network": {
        "clusters": {
          "__iprange": {
            "interface_config": {
              "framesize": "1500",
              "framesize_vm": "1500"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I also need to add other entries in different sections of the original json file.

Right now, I'm just trying to iterate over all the elements in test.json.  Eventually I want to build a path to each element in test.json and match it with path from mod.json to modify test.json.  However, I can't get all the elements printed in the original file.  My current code:

```
import json
import pprint

def traverse(d, path=None):
    if path is None:
        path = []
    for item,val  in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            for k,v in item.iteritems():
                print k
                traverse(v)
        elif isinstance(item, list):
            for j in item:
                (traverse(j))
        else:
            print item
        if isinstance(val, dict):
            for k,v in val.iteritems():
                print k
                traverse(v)
        elif isinstance(val, list):
            for j in val:
                (traverse(j))
with open("test.json", "r") as jf:
    data = json.load(jf)
traverse(data)
```

The output of the above is:

```
$ ./now.py
install
site
acls
dns
authorized_ports
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./now.py", line 51, in <module>
    traverse(data)
  File "./now.py", line 23, in traverse
    traverse(v)
  File "./now.py", line 23, in traverse
    traverse(v)
  File "./now.py", line 26, in traverse
    (traverse(j))
  File "./now.py", line 9, in traverse
    for item,val  in d.iteritems():
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iteritems'
```

I know my first `iteritems` call is in the wrong place but I just can't get my mind around recursion...  Any pointers appreciated.  Btw, I'm on Python 2.

**EDIT**

The actual json I'm trying to process is more complex than what was listed above.  Here is an edited version:

```
{
  "install": {
    "site": {
      "acls": {
        "dns": {
          "authorized_ports": ["53:tcp", "53:udp"]
        }
      },
      "network": {
        "clusters": {
          "__ip_range_1__": {
            "dhcpstart": "__ip__",
            "dhcpend": "__ip__",
            "adminip": "__ip__"
          },
          "__ip_range_2__": {
            "dhcpstart": "__ip__",
            "dhcpend": "__ip__",
            "adminip": "__ip__"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  "config": {
    "ippool": [
      {
        "pool_name": "/ippool1",
        "pool_description": "IP Pool1",
        "ranges": [["__ip__", "__ip__"]]
      },
      {
        "pool_name": "/ippool2",
        "pool_description": "IP Pool2",
        "ranges": [["__ip__", "__ip__"]]
      }
    ],
    "storage": [
      {
        "account": "/root",
        "credentials": {
          "account": "admin",
          "service": "storage",
          "user": "admin",
          "password": "pass"
        }
      }
    ]

  }
}
```

I modified Paul Panzer's answer to include lists as follows:

```
def traverse(d, path=[]):
    for k, v  in d.iteritems():
        yield path + [k], v
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            for k,v in traverse(v, path + [k]):
                yield k,v
        elif isinstance(v, list):
            for k in v:
                traverse(k, path + [])
```

However the above does not print elements inside the ippool and storage lists.  Once a list of dictionaries is encountered, it is not traversed for some reason.

Comment: Keys (`item`) can't be `list`s or `dict`s, so your first conditions are useless. You assume the `v` is a `dict` when the `val` is a `dict`, which isn't `True` and hence your error. You should just recurse `traverse(val)` when `val` is a `dict` and not iterate over `val`

Comment: so your test.json, at the top level, only has one key ('install'). Is the 'path' to your __ip_range_x always the same? e.g. always in 'install' > 'site' > 'network' > 'clusters' ?

Comment: @MaxPower my test.json has many entries at the top, some dict, some dict of dict and more complicated including many levels of dict and lists.  However, path to __ip_range_x is always the same.

Comment: Ok, in that case, does AChampion's answer work for you?

Comment: @MaxPower it produces too many values to unpack error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a cleaned up version of your `traverse` routine. It just traverses a nested dictionary/list; I've cut everything else for clarity. Hope it helps.

```
master = {
  "install": {
    "site": {
      "acls": {
        "dns": {
          "authorized_ports": ["53:tcp", "53:udp"]
        }
      },
      "network": {
        "clusters": {
          "__ip_range_1__": {
            "dhcpstart": "__ip__",
            "dhcpend": "__ip__",
            "adminip": "__ip__"
          },
          "__ip_range_2__": {
            "dhcpstart": "__ip__",
            "dhcpend": "__ip__",
            "adminip": "__ip__"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "config": {
    "ippool": [
      {
        "pool_name": "/ippool1",
        "pool_description": "IP Pool1",
        "ranges": [["__ip__", "__ip__"]]
      },
      {
        "pool_name": "/ippool2",
        "pool_description": "IP Pool2",
        "ranges": [["__ip__", "__ip__"]]
      }
    ],
    "storage": [
      {
        "account": "/root",
        "credentials": {
          "account": "admin",
          "service": "storage",
          "user": "admin",
          "password": "pass"
        }
      }
    ]

  }
}

def traverse(dict_or_list, path=[]):
    if isinstance(dict_or_list, dict):
        iterator = dict_or_list.iteritems()
    else:
        iterator = enumerate(dict_or_list)
    for k, v in iterator:
        yield path + [k], v
        if isinstance(v, (dict, list)):
            for k, v in traverse(v, path + [k]):
                yield k, v

for path, node in traverse(master):
    print path
```

Output:

```
['config']
['config', 'ippool']
['config', 'ippool', 0]
['config', 'ippool', 0, 'ranges']
['config', 'ippool', 0, 'ranges', 0]
['config', 'ippool', 0, 'ranges', 0, 0]
['config', 'ippool', 0, 'ranges', 0, 1]
['config', 'ippool', 0, 'pool_name']
['config', 'ippool', 0, 'pool_description']
['config', 'ippool', 1]
['config', 'ippool', 1, 'ranges']
['config', 'ippool', 1, 'ranges', 0]
['config', 'ippool', 1, 'ranges', 0, 0]
['config', 'ippool', 1, 'ranges', 0, 1]
['config', 'ippool', 1, 'pool_name']
['config', 'ippool', 1, 'pool_description']
['config', 'storage']
['config', 'storage', 0]
['config', 'storage', 0, 'credentials']
['config', 'storage', 0, 'credentials', 'account']
['config', 'storage', 0, 'credentials', 'password']
['config', 'storage', 0, 'credentials', 'user']
['config', 'storage', 0, 'credentials', 'service']
['config', 'storage', 0, 'account']
['install']
['install', 'site']
['install', 'site', 'acls']
['install', 'site', 'acls', 'dns']
['install', 'site', 'acls', 'dns', 'authorized_ports']
['install', 'site', 'acls', 'dns', 'authorized_ports', 0]
['install', 'site', 'acls', 'dns', 'authorized_ports', 1]
['install', 'site', 'network']
['install', 'site', 'network', 'clusters']
['install', 'site', 'network', 'clusters', '__ip_range_2__']
['install', 'site', 'network', 'clusters', '__ip_range_2__', 'dhcpend']
['install', 'site', 'network', 'clusters', '__ip_range_2__', 'adminip']
['install', 'site', 'network', 'clusters', '__ip_range_2__', 'dhcpstart']
['install', 'site', 'network', 'clusters', '__ip_range_1__']
['install', 'site', 'network', 'clusters', '__ip_range_1__', 'dhcpend']
['install', 'site', 'network', 'clusters', '__ip_range_1__', 'adminip']
['install', 'site', 'network', 'clusters', '__ip_range_1__', 'dhcpstart']
```

Comment: Thank you, the above works nicely.  However, I failed to show how complex my actual json really is.  It also contains lists of nested dictionaries - hence my attempt to process those as well.  I'll update my question with expanded json.  If you could add code for processing lists as well, I'll gladly accept your answer.

Comment: @Lidia added lists. Let me know whether it is what you had it mind.

Answer (score 3):

Seems you are looking to make this more complicated than necessary:

```
with open("test.json", "r") as jf:
    data = json.load(jf)
with open("mod.json", "r") as mf:
    mod = json.load(mf)

ip_ranges = data['install']['site']['network']['clusters']
for rng, val in mod['install']['site']['network']['clusters'].items():
    data[rng]["interface_config"] = val["interface_config"]
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error when executing the above:   
    for rng, val in mod['install']['site']['network']['clusters']:
    ValueError: too many values to unpack - is it because val is a dict?

Comment: Sorry missed `.items()` it's a `dict`.

Comment: This is still not working, got the following error:  `KeyError: u'__iprange'`.  This is the place where two jsons, original and mod, don't match.  Also, `ip_ranges` in your code above is assigned a value but it's never used.  What was the intent?

Comment: It works if I change the assignment to `data['install']['site']['network']['clusters'][rng]["interface_config"] = new_value`.  I'll add the corrected code as a separate answer cause data and mod are also reversed.

Answer (score 0):

Modified code from AChampion that works for adding entries under all elements of a dictionary that has a dynamic key:

```
with open(args.masterjson, "r") as masterjf:
    data = json.load(masterjf)
with open(args.modjson, "r") as modjf:
    mod = json.load(modjf)

new_value = mod['install']['site']['network']['clusters']['__iprange']['interface_config']
for rng, val in data['install']['site']['network']['clusters'].items():
    data['install']['site']['network']['clusters'][rng]["interface_config"] = new_value
```

The above adds a new dictionary of dictionaries under each ip range in clusters.  Output:

```
master BEFORE update:
{u'dhcpend': u'__ip__', u'adminip': u'__ip__', u'dhcpstart': u'__ip__'}
{u'dhcpend': u'__ip__', u'adminip': u'__ip__', u'dhcpstart': u'__ip__'}
master AFTER update:
{'interface_config': {u'framesize_vm': u'1500', u'framesize': u'1500'}, u'dhcpend': u'__ip__', u'adminip': u'__ip__', u'dhcpstart': u'__ip__'}
{'interface_config': {u'framesize_vm': u'1500', u'framesize': u'1500'}, u'dhcpend': u'__ip__', u'adminip': u'__ip__', u'dhcpstart': u'__ip__'}
```